# Component updates even though prop has not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a MapBox component that gets it data from the parent component.

I am trying to avoid updating the component everytime a state change is happening in the parent component. Even though shouldComponentUpdate logs the same props, it updates...

[image]
Map Child

```
    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.props.data.features !== null){
            this.fetchMap();
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log('now:', this.props.data)
        console.log('next', nextProps.data)
        if (this.props.data === nextProps.data) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.props.data !== nextProps.data) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
            this.fetchMap();
        }
    }
    fetchMap() {
        const { data } = this.props
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.mapContainer,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
            center: [8.32, 60.44],
            zoom: 5,
        })

        map.on('load', () => {

                map.addSource('locations', {
                    type: 'geojson',
                    data
                });
        });
    }

   .... render and return bla bla
```

Parent:

```
const Parent () => {
   const [state, change] = useState(false)
   return (
     <Button onClick={change(!state)}>Sorter</Button> // click and <Map> rerenders
     <Map setDraw={setDraw} data={geojson} />
   )
}
```

Comment: Dont' try a `===` compare instead try `shallowCompare` or use `React.PureComponent` and see if that helps.

Comment: simplify this ` if (this.props.data === nextProps.data){return false;}  if(this.props.data !== nextProps.data) {return true;}`

with return `this.props!==nextProps`

Comment: @Panther I tried chaning to `React.PureComponent` and removing `shouldComponentUpdate`. It still re-renders. Isn't shallowCompare the same thing?

Comment: Then its a good time to debug. Basically you need to write your own shallow compare and see which props changes and why they change and how to avoid it.

Comment: @Panther What would be the best way to go forward? May it be because the data  object is quite large and nested, that it doesn't understand that there is no difference?

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 way to realize it

1  parent call state use callback function way, which force object into a new one.

```
this.setState((state) => { 
return  {...state};
 });
```

you can check this api in: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

2 deep compare means you need to check the item in array one by one .Or violiently, I will turn array or object into string and then compare then.

3 you can create component for each item in array and then compare the difference in each component.

```
const geojson = {
    id:0,// +1 when changed
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: locations
};
```

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {// becacuse nextProps are always a different object from props
    if (this.props.data.id === nextProps.data.id) {
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure how to implement the third option that you are talking about. Can you show an example?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand your code. The third is not work for u. How do u setState in parent can you show it? I think the first one can solve it.

Comment: I set state using hooks. `const [state, change] = useState(false)` and then change state by `change(!state)` for example.

Comment: try to use functional updates, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates. I think what you change return the same object.

Comment: I am noticing that it doesn’t really re-render. It flickers and reinitializes the map. This does not happen if the state change happens in the same component. It only happens if the change is in a parent component.

Comment: I have created a Codesandbox that shows the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjq7j5x6jq

Comment: I will use compare `JSON.stringify(this.props.data) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.data)`, might be the quickest way to solve it. If data's length change, you can check it by length `this.props.data.length=== nextProps.data.length`. Finally, if it's possible, what about add id to geojson every time you change the data, and compare the  id to check whether it changed ``